# Maintaining multiple data providers and migration approaches in SQL

Tags: database-design

Consider the synchronization of Basketball matches from an external provider. For this, I have two tables, the `match` table:

```
+----+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id |         date         | home_team | away_team |
+----+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 67 | 2021-07-28 19:45:002 | France    | USA       |
+----+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

and also an `external_match` table:

```
+-----------------+----+
|   external_id   | id |
+-----------------+----+
| 8e73rekk0lreppj | 67 |
+-----------------+----+
```

Now I want to bring in a second provider, which also has this exact match, but with different attributes, like the country, etc.. Then, the idea is to have an implementation 'switch' to be able to change at any time between providers. My solution is to update the `match` table in the following way:

```
+----+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+
| id | universal_id |        date         | home_team | away_team | country | provider |
+----+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+
| 67 | 62fef7b1770a | 2021-07-28 19:45:00 | France    | USA       |         |        1 |
| 68 | 62fef7b1770a | 2021-07-28 19:45:00 | France    | USA       | Japan   |        2 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

and then the `external_match` table might become:

```
+-----------------+----+
|   external_id   | id |
+-----------------+----+
| 8e73rekk0lreppj | 67 |
| 18072481        | 68 |
+-----------------+----+
```

There is now an `universal_id`, which is an unique `id` for the exact same matches across different providers and also a `provider` column which is used to filter by provider. Notice the different values in `external_id` column, because those entries come from different providers. Then, to query all matches by provider:

```sql
select * from match
...
where provider = ?
```

and I think it works. **However, it's still unclear how to generate the `universal_id`**, and there are many more entities besides the `match` table, like `team`, `player` etc.. there must be some kind of data matching logic, right? but how is it typically done? and in terms of SQL?

Furthermore, consider some user related data that is indexed by the `id` column of `match` table. **Now, this content needs to be migrated to use the `universal_id` right?** otherwise it will only show if the 'switch' is set for one of the providers.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

This is a repost of this [Database Administrators Stack Exchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299512/maintaining-multiple-data-providers-and-migration-approaches-in-sql).

Comment: Relational databases represent real-world facts - so if there is no universal identification method for those matches in the real world, you can guess why the situation is the same in your computer model. Perhaps you can use the GPS coordinates of the stadium where the match is played, and the date/time of the play?

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple sites. [Help]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database that is always available, then it could have a table like

**matches(id, prov1id, prov2id)**

and whenever you need to match prov1id and prov2id, you can refer to this table. If you need to always switch between providers, then you can invent a formula that generates a uniquely identifiable key, maybe encoding the match place, time and teams respectively and use that encoding to generate the ids which would therefore automatically match. Nevertheless, you will need to regularly synchronize your provider-info, because some matches may have created/modified/removed in the meantime.